# mysql query on 2 tables with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One is called `artist`. Here is the table structure:

```
artistID lastname firstname nationality dateofbirth datedcease
```

The other table is called `work`

```
workId title copy medium description artist ID
```

What is the SQL query to list the details of any works of art (including artist who created the work) that have more than one copy recorded in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  w.copy, w.title, w.description, w.medium, 
  a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname AS 'Artist created the work'
FROM artists a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM work 
    WHERE artistID IN
    ( 
        SELECT artistID
        FROM work 
        GROUP BY artistID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    )
) w ON a.artistID = w.artistID
```

Here is a [**demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97562/3)